# Laravel MySQL connection on Cloudcontrolled

Tags: mysql, laravel, cloudcontrol

I am using the Laravel framework for a project hosted on cloudcontrol.com and would like to connect to a MySQLd instance on cloudcontrol.com.

How can I configure DB access in Laravel? Unfortunately I could not find any documentation for this framework.

Comment: Laravel 4 : http://laravel.com/docs/database,
Laravel 3 : http://three.laravel.com/docs/database/config

I still cannot believe you could not find Laravel documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Since Laravel uses PHP for it's configuration, you can simply follow the example from our documentation to read the credentials from the environment. Simply adjust `app/config/database.php` accordingly.

https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Platform%20Documentation#add-on-credentials

Answer (score 0):

You can configure database settings in `app/config/database.php`.